# Mediaelement.js videos black screen but can hear audio on iOS

Tags: ios, html, video, html5-video, mediaelement.js

On my page I have 2 mediaelement players. One is an audio player that works fine. The other is a video player.

I'm using an mp4 for cross browser/device compatibility. It works everywhere without issue. The only issue I'm having is on iOS, the video plays, but the screen is black and I can only hear the audio. I've looked everywhere and tried different types of encoding but cannot solve this issue.

If I set iPadUseNativeControls: true, the video will work in the native player, but it appears on the screen really small and not centered, breaking the layout.

As an aside, I'm initializing the players via new MediaElementPlayer() as opposed to $().mediaelementplayer()

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue with Android. Tested with Firefox Mobile 25, Firefox Beta 26 and Chrome 31. None which worked. Black picture but I can hear audio.
I can use the video player and watch the videos on Android; which tells me the MP4 encoding is fine.